# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ☯ (U+262F)

Tags: errors, unicode, input-encodings

I encountered this error while trying to compile my thesis.
Before I did not have this error.

Any idea how I can find this Unicode character in my LaTeX document, or solve this issue?

Comment: Are you bound to pdflatex or open to xe-/lualatex?

Comment: I am bount to pdflatex

Comment: There is `\Yinyang` in the `marvosym` package

Answer (score 11):

to more easily find it add

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{262F}{YIN YANG HERE!!!!!}
```

to your preamble, and search the output for that text. If you want it to display then find a yinyang.pdf image and do something like

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{262F}{\includegraphics[height=1ex]{yinyang}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the yingyang symbol. It was generated by the Bibtex file due to an automatic recognition of a paper.

Comment: The issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with Ti*k*Z:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,blindtext}
\newcommand{\yingyang}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3,baseline=-.1cm]
                            \draw[thick,fill=black] circle(1);
                            \fill[white] (0,-.5) circle(.1);
                            \fill[white] (0,-1) arc(-90:-270:.5) arc(-90:90:.5) arc(90:270:1) -- cycle;
                            \fill[black] (0,.5) circle(.1);
                        \end{tikzpicture}
                       }
\begin{document}
    \blindtext\yingyang\blindtext\yingyang
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT:** Just type `[… ,rotate=-90]` to get your desired yin-yang-character.